# How to rename all items in a ListBox control

Tags: vb.net, listbox

How to rename `ListBox` contains following items

`C:\Logs\2016-09-28-2.log`
`C:\Logs\2016-09-28-1.log`

to

`C:\Logs\2016-09-28-2.log.gz`
`C:\Logs\2016-09-28-1.log.gz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using WinForms, you can modify the properties of items in a ListBox via the [Items property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx). This returns a ListBox.ObjectCollection. You can index into this collection and modify the individual items.

Generally, items in a ListBox are just strings, so assigning a new string to the appropriate index in the Items collection will change the text in the ListBox. However, they can actually be any type of object. Check the code that adds the items to the ListBox in the first place to make sure that they are strings. If they are something else, you'll need to modify that data structure accordingly.

To do this for *all* of the items in the list, you will need to use a loop that loops through the entire Items collection.

For example:

```
For i As Integer = 0 to (myListBox.Items().Count - 1)
    myListBoxItems.Items(i) = myListBox.Items(i) + ".gz"
Next
```

If it is not guaranteed that all items in the ListBox should have the `.gz` extension added to them, you will need to use a conditional statement inside of the body of the loop that first tests the current value of the string to decide whether to append the extension.

Comment: That gave an error upon executing the code, `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll` , `Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.`, although I did find a workaround, so the problem is solved now, thanks for trying anyways.

Comment: The loop should be `For i As Integer = 0 to myListBox.Items().Count - 1` (with: minus one)

Comment: Of course it should. Thanks, @Oliver! In the future, please don't be bashful about editing to fix code mistakes in my answers. I know not everyone likes this, but I don't see anything wrong with it. I often miss comments because I get hundreds of those notifications per day, and just don't have time to go through them all. I happened to see this one, so I've already fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

For a minimal solution, Try the following code

```
Dim MyList = (From lst In ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)() Select lst & ".gz").ToList

ListBox1.DataSource = MyList
```